# PHP crypt salt generation

Tags: php, encryption, crypt

I am generating salt for php [crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function like this

```
$hashSalt = substr(md5(time().uniqid(rand())),0, 22);

$hashedPassword = crypt('SmithJohn', '$2a$07$'.$hashSalt.'$');
```

From my understanding this is a good method. What are your thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure random number generation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182584/secure-random-number-generation-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too complicated and not necessarily random enough. Use sources that are made for that purpose:

```
mcrypt_create_iv($salt_len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)
```

or

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($salt_len)
```

or

```
$buffer = '';
$f = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
$read = strlen($buffer);
while ($read < $salt_len) {
    $buffer .= fread($f, $salt_len - $read);
    $read = strlen($buffer);
}
fclose($f);
```

Preferably all used as several layers of fallback, as shown in https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php#L84

Comment: Why we need fopen here?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182584/secure-random-number-generation-in-php/1551064#1551064) has more details about secure random number generation in PHP.

Comment: @phpsessionid Because it's a fallback method to read from `/dev/urandom`. If you don't know what that is, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/urandom.